# Cooking with ground rabbit

Tags: substitutions, rabbit

A few months ago I bought some ground rabbit.  I had sort of forgotten about it until the other day.  I've tried looking up recipes for ground rabbit, but all of the rabbit recipes I've found call for cubes or pieces. If I substitute ground rabbit in spaghetti sauce or chili, would it taste gamey (I know that's somewhat subjective but I haven't eaten rabbit since I was very small so I don't remember how gamey it was but it was a wild rabbit not one raised to be food)?  Would the spaghetti sauce or chili overpower the rabbit?

According to [Rabbit Substitute?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28938/rabbit-substitute), rabbit is a gamier version of chicken. So, theoretically could I substitute ground rabbit where I might use ground chicken?  Could I also make rabbit burgers out of the ground rabbit or would that be too gamey (I sometimes make burgers using ground chicken, salsa, and shredded or crumbled cheese)?

This question [Substitute rabbit in chicken recipes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24447/substitute-rabbit-in-chicken-recipes) sort of asks what I'm looking for, but there's no real answer.

I hope I'm not too off topic or asking a question that's not allowed.  I'm not looking for recipes, just options to substitute ground rabbit in recipes I already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen ground rabbit, but I've eaten rabbit many times in Spain grilled in the BBQ or in a Paella. Rabbit can compare to chicken. The meat is a bit tougher than chicken but not gamey at all. At least the farm rabbits I ate.

So I would say that yes, you should be able to use this ground meat as a substitute of chicken in a sauce and I don't even think that you will ever notice the difference.

If you are going to make hamburgers (and I would do just to be able to say that I ate a rabbit hamburger), maybe you could mix the meat with chopped onion, breadcrumbs and egg to make it moister.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I was thinking along the same lines - that it would be cool to say I had a rabbit burger.  Is it like poultry where you want to cook it through, or is it more like beef where you can have it a little rarer?

Comment: I really don't know about rabbit, but I would definitely stay on the safe side. When I cook chicken hamburgers (usually mixed with chopped onion), after I sear them, I add some water in the pan and I let it cook covered with the steam until the center is done. That way, the hamburgers stay moist even if they are well done. I only eat rare ground beef meat, and only when my butcher grounded it the same day in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

I use both ground and whole rabbit in the same way I use chicken, it also makes an excellent breakfast sausage